# JS scrollIntoView and scrollBy refuse to work with a simple tab script in a very strange way

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I am trying to write simple tabs for my webpage. I pretty much copy-pasted  [w3schools tab example](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp), and it works fine. The issue is, when I attempt to scroll down to the opened tab using JS `scrollIntoView` or `scrollBy`, it instead goes to the top of the page. It doesn't matter which arguments I pass, as long as functions containing `scrollIntoView` or `scrollBy` have anything to do with tabs JS or HTML elements of tabs, they behave the same way. This happens even when `scrollIntoView` and `scrollBy` are called from other functions. They work fine with all other elements on the page, however - just the tab elements present a problem.

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/budgieweb/pen/akAzbd

Here's the function that deals with the tabs:

```
        function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        // Declare all variables
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

        // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }

        // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        //code that's supposed to scroll to the tab
        document.getElementById(cityName).scrollIntoView(true);
    }
```

Here's HTML:

```
  <ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Thing is, even if I write something like

```
 <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick"testFunction(event, 'London')"">London</a></li>

 <script>
 function testFunction(evt, cityName) {
  openCity(evt, cityName);
  window.scrollBy(0, 500);
  }
 </script>
```

it still just opens the tab and sends me to the top of the page.

even if I call a function that does `window.Scrollby(0, 500)` at the last line of `openCity` function, it doesn't scroll. Yet if I add a completely separate button that calls a scroll function onclick, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: A jsFiddle would be useful for this.

Comment: https://codepen.io/budgieweb/pen/akAzbd - here it is, and added a link to the question.